# I am trying to run mosaic on a band and at this stage while i am applying raster it is giving me this error

Tags: r, raster, gdal, mosaic, mosaic-plot

```
band1<-raster(B1)
Error in if (x == "" | x == ".") { : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: what is `B1`?  I am guessing a zero length character.

Comment: B1 is the name of the file where Band 1 images are saved.

Comment: I doubt that. Please edit your question to show that (print B1 before running this example).

Answer (score 0):

That suggests that B1 is an empty string

```
library(raster)
B1 <- character()
B1
# character(0)
raster(B1)
# Error in if (x == "" | x == ".") { : argument is of length zero
```